# Em php como executar determinada função após passados X dias da ultima execução

Tags: php, datetime, cakephp-2

Estou elaborando mudanças e rotinas em um aplicativo web criado em PHP e CakePHP, no caso uma das rotinas seria um Component executado a cada 15 dias , para atualizar um arquivo .html
Como no PHP verifico se foi passado X dias da ultima execução de determinada rotina?

Pensei no seguinte algorítimo, porém é a maneira 'elegante' de fazer a verificação?, como codificar o algorítimo?.

1- pegar os milissegundos gravados em um arquivo texto.
2- pegar os milissegundos atuais.
3- se não tiver nada no arquivo texto, ou os milissegundos atuais for maior ou igual que, os milissegundos gravados no arquivo mais o valor de X dias em milissegundos.
4- gravar os milissegundos atuais no arquivo texto.

Answer (score 6):

Uma possibilidade seria algo como ter no mínimo o *path* de localização dos arquivos e a informação retornado por [filemtime()](http://www.php.net/filemtime) de cada um deles armazenados num banco de dados.

Acessadas por uma determinada URL, você consultaria essas informações e, preferivelmente com a [DateTime](http://www.php.net/class.datetime), compararia se 15 dias se passaram e caso positivo, executaria a sua rotina sobre os arquivos.

Essa abordagem tem no mínimo três problemas:

1. Requer que alguém acesse manualmente essa URL
2. Se forem muitos arquivos, a rotina ficará bastante sobrecarregada, principalmente no loop

   2.1 Você poderia ter problemas de *timeout* por causa disso

Para solucionar o primeiro problema e, de repente, os outros dois ao mesmo tempo, você associaria isso à um CronJob configurado para ser executado a cada 15 dias.

Mas pensa comigo: Se uma determinada rotina deve ocorrer a cada 15 dias, pra quê manter uma lista de arquivos, *timestamps* da data de modificação, loops, comparações e etc. se simplesmente criar uma rotina que afete todos os arquivos de 15 em 15 dias resolve?

Responda-se à essa pergunta e você verá que com CronJobs você resolve tudo com os pés nas costas. ;)

Comment: ``CronJobs`` +1

Answer (score 4):

Não vejo problema em utilizar uma data comum para esse calculo se você não precisar dessa precisão de milisegundos.

Minha ideia seria utilizar a classe `DateTime` para verificar a diferença de 15 dias

```
<?php

// Algum metodo de alguma classe
function getUltimaExecucao(){

    // Formato Y-m-d
    //$data = getLastDate();

    $data = '2014-06-30';

    return DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $data);;
}

// Execução

$dataUltimaExecucao = getUltimaExecucao();
$dataAtual = new DateTime();

$diferenca = $dataAtual->diff($dataUltimaExecucao);
$diferencaEmDias = $diferenca->format('%a');

if ($diferencaEmDias >= 15 ){
    echo "Se passaram $diferencaEmDias dias" . PHP_EOL;
};

echo "FIM";
```

Como comentado em outras respostas, prefira executar essa função num [`cronjob`](http://www.infowester.com/linuxcron.php) em ambiente *unix, ou [`schtasks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (cmd) / [`New-JobTrigger`](http://www.mcsesolution.com/Windows-Server-League/automatizando-tarefas-com-o-windows-powershell-30.html) (Powershell) em ambientes Windows.