# Envio de email programado com PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Salve pessoal, sou novo aqui e estou com uma dúvida muito peculiar. Estou desenvolvendo um sistema (CodeIgniter + MySQL) que registra alguns eventos e deve enviar um email em uma data pré definida, algo em torno de oito ou nove meses a frente. Como consigo programar o envio desse email para que quando chegar essa data o email seja enviado sem intervenção do usuário?

Comment: Celson, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. Você pode utilizar cron jobs para isso. Já temos varias perguntas aqui relacionadas a isso, [essa por exemplo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27410/em-php-como-executar-determinada-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ap%C3%B3s-passados-x-dias-da-ultima-execu%C3%A7%C3%A3o/27421#27421).

Answer (score 1):

Muitos sistemas acontecem isso, tem um evento que irá ser em uma data específica e tem que disparar um e-mail em um determinado período antes para notificar.

O que fiz foi criar uma `cronjob` e essa minha rotina chama um `controller/metodo` que faz uma leitura na tabela que tem os eventos e com isso disparar os e-mails.

Eu aconselho dar uma olhada na própria documentação http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html

Answer (score 0):

O que eu faria é o seguinte, crie um campo data nesta tabela e esse campo vai receber essa data que vai ser para definir o dia do envio, crie um arquivo básico em PHP e usando só PHP sem nada de HTML e neste arquivo você cria uma função que busque esse campo data e verifique se é igual a data atual e se for você dispara o Email para a pessoa.

Este arquivo que cuida do envio você cria um tarefa em sua hospedagem pra rodar ele de tempo em tempo ai sim fica automático o envio sem intervenção humana.

Se tiver algum dúvida de como fazer tudo isso é só dar um toque.

Comment: Até entendi a utilização do crontab para automatizar a tarefa, mas como "executar" o arquivo .php se ele não é executavel? voce poderia me mostrar algum exemplo?

Comment: Maneira mais fácil seria algo parecido com o exemplo do link: http://www.cybernetfx.com/clientes/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=81

Comment: Ai você vai na sua hospedagem e verifica se ele possui esse serviço, sim o php não é executável mas mas o agendamento de tarefa vai la e "executa" seu php pra ele rodar em background e assim ele "executa" tudo o que tem no arquivo php e é por isso que não pode ter html dentro dele tem que ser php puro.