# Como fazer webservice rodar sem interação de usuário?

Tags: php, web-service

Então galera, estou querendo criar um webservice em PHP que vai fazer tudo através de outro webservice(por sua API). Ele vai verificar se tem alguma mensagem, tendo, ele processa e retorna uma mensagem apropriada.

Minha pergunta é: Como fazer esse webservice rodar?

Ele tem que rodar automaticamente, sozinho. Não sei como fazer isso em PHP.

Sei que existem linguagens mais apropriadas para o que eu quero, mas PHP é o que eu tenho no momento.

Alguma luz?

Comment: Qual sistema operacional está usando no servidor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer o que você deseja o PHP irá precisar de uma "ajudinha" de fora: do SO do seu servidor.

Conceitualmente você irá utilizar um `cronjob` para executar seu serviço de tempos em tempos via linha de comando:

```
 > * * * * * php -f /path/pro/meu/script.php
```

Em um server Windows, você pode fazer a mesma coisa com [*Schedule Tasks*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27421/4751)

Ai a parte do seu código basta fazer as chamadas ao webservice normalmente.

Answer (score 2):

Ao invés de criar outro webservice, pode usar o serviço [A trigger](http://atrigger.com/)

É um serviço **GRATUITO** no qual você se cadastra e agenda a chamada de uma Url em intervalo de tempo pré determinado. Se preferir, pode também utilizar a [library deles para PHP](http://atrigger.com/docs/wiki/14/library-php). O agendamento da chamada ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
// referencia a library baixada
require_once("/path/to/atriggerphp/ATrigger.php");
// utiliza a chave e o segredo criados ao se cadastrar
ATrigger::init("YOUR_APIKey","YOUR_APISecret");
// a tag identifica qual é tarefa agendada no serviço
$tags = array();
$tags['type']='test';

//agenda a chamada no tempo que quiser: Xminute, Xhour, Xday, Xmonth, Xyear
// a cada 1 hora = 1hour
ATrigger::doCreate("1hour", "http://www.meudominio.com/tarefa?param", $tags);

// para pausar a tarefa
ATrigger::doPause($tags);
```

Answer (score 1):

Bem "complexa" essa sua pergunta no sentindo do entendimento.
Vou dar a minha sugestão pelo o que eu entendi.

Se você quer automatizar alguma coisa, pense se essa forma que você está desejando, ou seja, criar um WEBSERVICE, para puxar as informações de outro, seja a melhor solução.

Na antiga empresa (trabalhamos com java e python) quando queríamos realizar algum processo desses, que não tenha interação humana, utilizamos um agendador de tarefas, em inglês *schedule* . Desta forma, o próprio servidor já faz todo o procedimento, conforme o tempo especificado por você

Se puder, seja mais específico no que pretende fazer e etc. Assim, acho que o pessoal consegue te dar uma ajuda BEM melhor.

Comment: Então, minha idéia é criar um serviço dentro dentro de um mensageiro utilizando sua API. Então meu serviço vai receber as mensagens, processá-las e enviar uma mensagem de volta. a API não vai me mandar nada, meu serviço que tem que verificar se tem mensagens. Não haverá interação do usuário direta com o meu serviço, logo, nada para "arrancá-lo", fazê-lo funcionar. Ele tem que automaticamente checar se tem mensagens e esse é o meu problema, como fazer o código "rodar sozinho". Vou editar a pergunta para deixá-la mais "entendível".

Comment: Como havia desenhado em minha resposta, existem sim um schedule par ao php, como o pessoal respondeu a baixo. Para o seu caso, esta forma que te falei, certamente funcionará.